# accessing to related objects of a parent class

Tags: python, django

take a look at my models:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
   HeadImage = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery",editable=True,blank=True,null=True)

class Image(models.Model):
   Image = models.ImageField(upload_to="gallery")
   Gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name='images')

class Tour(Gallery):
   Category=models.ForeignKey(TourCategory)
   Name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
   Count=models.SmallIntegerField()
```

Now,I have a Tour object that I wanna access to image_set of Tour object,some thing like this:

```
{% for i in tour.gallery_ptr.images.all %}
        <img src="{{MEDIAL_URL}}{{i.Image.url}}" width="500px" height="400px"/>
{% endfor %}
```

but this doesn't work,How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying this in the shell it works fine.  Getting all images for a tour object through `tour.gallery_ptr.images.all()`  will yield all image objects.  You might have to perform this operation in your view and not in your template.

Additionally, when something fails in a template it fails silently.  Trying this in your view you will get the nice big errors telling you exactly what went wrong.

Comment: I tryed it out in a view,but no error!I can access 'tour.gallery_ptr.HeadImage' but 'tour.gallery_ptr.images.all' has no results!